# Module Mapping in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an older application that was built on .net 2.0 and II6.  It uses an httpmodule to rewrite .mp3 urls to asp.net to be processed.

The urls look like this: /somepath/sound.mp3 It worked fine until we upgraded to IIS7.  I believe that I have to update the "Handler Mappings" in IIS, but I'm sure having issues with it.  I'm just getting 404's.

My Mapping looks like this, but fails to work:

Request Path: *.mp3
Executable: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
Name: Engine Mp3

All verbs, no to "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to", Script access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731285(WS.10).aspx